# Why would one format date in logs using "%c"?

Tags: python, logging, language-lawyer, date-formatting

A widely used piece of code sets the default `datefmt` in [`logging.Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter) to `"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z"` (same as `"%c"` in C locale).

The code was written 12+ years ago and the author is unavailable.

I have never seen such log formatting before.
I find `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` more convenient (it sorts chronologically the same as lexicographically and is shorter). I am trying to figure out what the rationale might have been.

Comment: Your title askes about using `"%c"`, but the body asks about `"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z"`. Can you reconcile that? (the underlying question is just "Why use anything but ISO format?", but the mismatch just confuses matters)

Comment: `"%c"` in C locale is identical to `"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z"`

Comment: Sure, but there are arguments for `"%c"` (useful to locale users) that wouldn't apply to `"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z"`. If the question is really just "Why use anything but ISO-8601 format?", ask that question. If the question is specific to "Why use this specific format?", be consistent on what you're asking about. I'll note, I don't really see it mattering too much; ISO-8601 is useful for the sorting behavior, but in logs, the logs are typically already sorted (being emitted chronologically), so the sorting benefit is less meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same default format used by the `date` utility on most *nix systems and is intended to be more human-readable than an ISO 8601-ish format. I would assume this decision was made to stay consistent with preestablished defaults.